# Best way to move certain rows out of one object to another

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

just wondering what is the best way to filter out data from one object to another using an array

I want to move the entire rows within `selected_city_codes` from `airport_data_1` to `airport_data_2`

```
airport_data_1 = [{"departure_time":"12:00","arrival_time":"03:00","city_id":"BOS"},  
{"departure_time" :"12:00","arrival_time":"03:00","city_id":"BOS"},
{"departure_time" :"01:00","arrival_time":"04:00","city_id":"SFO"},
{"departure_time" :"03:00","arrival_time":"05:00","city_id":"BOS"},
{"departure_time" :"03:00","arrival_time":"05:00","city_id":"SFO"},
{"departure_time" :"04:00","arrival_time":"06:00","city_id":"SJC"},
{"departure_time" :"04:00","arrival_time":"06:00","city_id":"JFK"},
{"departure_time" :"06:00","arrival_time":"09:00","city_id":"SJC"}];

airport_data_2 = [];

selected_city_codes = ['SJC','JFK']; //items to remove from `airport_data_1` to `airport_data_2`

//my attempt to remove the listed values from selected_city_codes
for(i in selected_city_codes) { 
    airport_data_2 = airport_data_2.filter(item => item.city_id != selected_city_codes[i]);
}
```

Desired result

```js
airport_data_1 = [{"departure_time":"12:00","arrival_time":"03:00","city_id":"BOS"},  
{"departure_time" :"12:00","arrival_time":"03:00","city_id":"BOS"},
{"departure_time" :"01:00","arrival_time":"04:00","city_id":"SFO"},
{"departure_time" :"03:00","arrival_time":"05:00","city_id":"BOS"},
{"departure_time" :"03:00","arrival_time":"05:00","city_id":"SFO"}]; 


airport_data_2 = [{"departure_time" :"04:00","arrival_time":"06:00","city_id":"SJC"},
{"departure_time" :"04:00","arrival_time":"06:00","city_id":"JFK"},
{"departure_time" :"06:00","arrival_time":"09:00","city_id":"SJC"}];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to filter the first array and use something like `includes` to check if `city_id` is in `selected_city_codes`:

```js
const airport_data_1 = [
  { departure_time: '12:00', arrival_time: '03:00', city_id: 'BOS' },
  { departure_time: '12:00', arrival_time: '03:00', city_id: 'BOS' },
  { departure_time: '01:00', arrival_time: '04:00', city_id: 'SFO' },
  { departure_time: '03:00', arrival_time: '05:00', city_id: 'BOS' },
  { departure_time: '03:00', arrival_time: '05:00', city_id: 'SFO' },
  { departure_time: '04:00', arrival_time: '06:00', city_id: 'SJC' },
  { departure_time: '04:00', arrival_time: '06:00', city_id: 'JFK' },
  { departure_time: '06:00', arrival_time: '09:00', city_id: 'SJC' },
];
const selected_city_codes = ['SJC', 'JFK'];

const airport_data_2 = airport_data_1.filter((el) =>
  selected_city_codes.includes(el.city_id)
);
console.log(airport_data_2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of [array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to split original array into two parts.

```js
const airport_data_1 = [{"departure_time":"12:00","arrival_time":"03:00","city_id":"BOS"},  
{"departure_time" :"12:00","arrival_time":"03:00","city_id":"BOS"},
{"departure_time" :"01:00","arrival_time":"04:00","city_id":"SFO"},
{"departure_time" :"03:00","arrival_time":"05:00","city_id":"BOS"},
{"departure_time" :"03:00","arrival_time":"05:00","city_id":"SFO"},
{"departure_time" :"04:00","arrival_time":"06:00","city_id":"SJC"},
{"departure_time" :"04:00","arrival_time":"06:00","city_id":"JFK"},
{"departure_time" :"06:00","arrival_time":"09:00","city_id":"SJC"}];


const selected_city_codes = ['SJC','JFK']; //items to remove from `airport_data_1` to `airport_data_2`


const data = airport_data_1.reduce((s, x) => { 
  s[ selected_city_codes.indexOf(x.city_id) < 0 ].push(x) ; return s;} , {true: [], false:[]} )

const data_1 = data.true;

const airport_data_2 = data.false;

console.log('airport_data_1 ', data_1);

console.log('airport_data_2 ', airport_data_2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```